# Sonos Application Code language

Tags: hardware, sonos

I was wondering if anyone could provide any guidance, I am intrigued as to how for example Sonos would have created the software / API for their hardware? where would they have started? what language would they have used?

I would love to learn how to code on a machine level basis and if anyone could shed any light or provide any guidance I'd be grateful

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Players all run Linux, so I'm sure somewhere on the web you can find what is involved in bringing up a Linux build on custom hardware.